# Create a function that will convert a parameter to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters

I need to create a function, that will parse function parameter of integer to an array list.

So if we call the function like this: `sum(1, 4 ,7);`
then inside of the function 'sum' the arguments variable/keyword will look like this `[1, 4, 7]`.
I need to create a sum function so that it can take any number of arguments and return the sum of all of them.

Here's my code so far:

```
function sum ([a,b]) {
var arr = [a,b];
var sum =arr.reduce(add, 0);

function add(a, b) {
return a + b;
}
}
```

I also was trying to so something like this:

```
function sum ({
  arr[0]: 1;
  arr[1]: 2;
  arr[2]:3;

  var sum =arr.reduce(add, 0);

function add(a, b) {
return a + b;
}
})
```

but I obviously doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function sun () {
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(pre, cur) {
    return pre + cur
  }, 0)
}
```

This is your need.

Comment: **Explain what you've done**.  Code only answers are not useful.  Also, you've got typos.  ALSO, you've baked "add" into this function, which is not what OP requested.

Comment: Thanks, but what is "pre" and "cur" in here? Just an elements of the array?

Comment: @AliceJarmusch this is two of the params of `Array.prototype.reduce` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @cale_b My mistake @AliceJarmusch  you wanna accumulation the params of function `sum`, but you don't know the count of the params. By the `arguments` in the function, you can get all the params like Array, but this is not Array. So you should use `.call` to execute `reduce` on it.

Comment: @AliceJarmusch In ES6, you shouldn't use `arguments` in the array, you should use `...args` operator get all the params. You can try @Tresdin answer in babel.

Comment: @TomIsion, thank you! It did work, and now I will learn more about params and Arrays in JS.

Comment: @AliceJarmusch Yep. They are different. You can see this [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). It like the `Array`, but don't have the `Array.prototype`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ES6 solution.

```
let sum = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

You can see the MDN article of [`rest parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) for more details. It is basically used for retrieving the list of arguments in an array.

Comment: Isn't it just the same as I'm trying to do? As I understand, the only issue here is to convert args to a list, and apply .reduce() to it. And I don't really know what I can do with it.

Comment: @AliceJarmusch You don't need a function to convert `arguments` to an array. Rest parameters were designed for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Just for changing `arguments` to an array of an array like object, you could use `Array.apply`.

Read more:

- [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```js
function x() {
    return Array.apply(Array, arguments);
}

var array = x(1, 4, 7);

console.log(array);
console.log(typeof array);
console.log(Array.isArray(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum =function() {
    var args = [];
    args.push.apply(args, arguments);
    return args.reduce((a,b) => { return a+b}, 0); // ES6 arrow function
}
sum(1,2,3); // return 6
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.